# uniform distribution in stan/R causes sampling error

Tags: r, stan

I am learning `rstan` and at the moment I'm solving exercises from Gelmans "Bayesian Data Analysis". For reference this is about the example 5 in chapter 3.

It keeps failing with:

```
Initialization failed after 100 attempts.  
Try specifying initial values, reducing ranges of constrained values, or reparameterizing the model.
error occurred during calling the sampler; sampling not done
```

this is my R code:

```
library(rstan)
scode <- "
transformed data {
  real o_data[5];  
  o_data[1] <- 10;
  o_data[2] <- 10;
  o_data[3] <- 12;
  o_data[4] <- 11;
  o_data[5] <- 9;  
}

parameters {  
  real mu;
  real<lower=0> sigma;
  real tru_val[5];
}

model { 
  mu ~ uniform(0.0,20.0);
  sigma ~ gamma(2,1);
  for (i in 1:5)   {     
    tru_val[i] ~ normal(mu,sigma);
    tru_val[i] ~ uniform(o_data[i]-0.5, o_data[i]+0.5);
  }
}
"

afit <- stan(model_code = scode, verbose=TRUE)
```

The funny thing is - if I change the second tru_val sampling to `tru_val[i] ~ normal(o_data[i],0.5);` the model will evaluate just fine.

So far I tried in the stan code:

- rearranging the sampling statements
- introducing helper variables
- explicitely writing `increment_log_p` statements
- change variable names in case I had accidentially used a keyword
- add print statements in the stan code
- setting mu to 10
- relaxing/widening the constraints in the uniform distribution
- and combinations of above

I noticed something surprising, as I printed the values of tru_val that - no matter which order the statements - I make it prints values around 0 typically between -2 and +2 - even when I set `mu <- 10; sigma <- 1;` (in the data section) and the sampling statement `tru_val[i] ~ uniform(9.5,10.5)`. I don't really see how it can get these numbers.

I really hope someone can shine some light onto this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constraints of the variable need to match the support of the distribution you're using. For `tru_val[i] ~ uniform(9.5, 10.5)`, `tru_val` has to be defined as `real<lower=9.5,upper=10.5> tru_val[5]`.

In this statement, `tru_val[i] ~ normal(mu, sigma)`, Stan is not drawing a sample from a normal distribution and setting it to `tru_val[i]`. It is calculating the joint distribution function (in log space); in this case, it's evaluating the normal probability distribution function of `tru_val[i]` given `mu` and `sigma` (in log space).

(The best place to ask questions is on the Stan users mailing list.)

Comment: Could you elaborate how a definition for my problem would look like -  tru_val[i] ~ uniform(o_data[i]-0.5, o_data[i]+0.5) would require different ranges for every entry (based on data). How does one define such an array?

Comment: Doing some reparametrization I could solve the problem finally. I'm not too happy with all this complex code, but probably should learn more STAN before complaining ;)

Comment: The bounds in Stan are currently not vectorized. They can be data or parameters, but not vectors. The real issue is with the way you're building your model. There's a discontinuity that essentially breaks Hamiltonian Monte Carlo.
One thing you can do is define a transformed parameter that is offset from a uniform(0,1) variable.

Comment: Thanks. That's actually what I finally did since the problem was easy enough. Still was wondering if there was a *general* way.